# How to authenticate proxy with username and password in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am trying to authenticate proxy with username and password in Selenium using Python but the current code is not working. I have tried many solutions but none of them worked.

Proxy example,

```
IP = xxx.xx.xx.xx
PORT = xxxxx
USERNAME = USERNAME
PASSWORD = PASSWORD
```

I have used the following code,

```
driver.execute_script("""
          Services.prefs.setIntPref('network.proxy.type', 1);
          Services.prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", arguments[0]);
          Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", arguments[1]);
          Services.prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.ssl", arguments[0]);
          Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.ssl_port", arguments[1]);
          Services.prefs.setCharPref('network.proxy.socks', arguments[4]);
          Services.prefs.setIntPref('network.proxy.socks_port', arguments[5]);
          Services.prefs.setCharPref('network.proxy.socks_username', arguments[6]);
          Services.prefs.setCharPref('network.proxy.socks_password', arguments[7]);
          """, http_addr, http_port, ssl_addr, ssl_port, socks_addr, socks_port, socks_username, socks_password)
```

I have tried some other code snippets also. I tried to place values into alert boxes also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). And it has Python binding [PyAutoIt](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/). Once you installed PyAutoIt using PIP - `pip install PyAutoIt`, the following code does your job.

```
import autoit

autoit.win_wait_active("Authentication Required") # title of the dialog box to wait. so it will wait for the Authentication Required dialog
autoit.send("username", 1) # second parameter is the mode (changes how "keys" is processed)
autoit.send("{TAB}") # press tab key to go to the password field
autoit.send("password", 1)
autoit.send("{Enter}") # press enter key
```

For more information about the second parameter in the send method, here is the code,

```
def send(send_text, mode=0):
    """
    Sends simulated keystrokes to the active window.
    :param send_text:
    :param mode: Changes how "keys" is processed:
        flag = 0 (default), Text contains special characters like + and ! to
         indicate SHIFT and ALT key presses.
        flag = 1, keys are sent raw.
    :return:
    """
    AUTO_IT.AU3_Send(LPCWSTR(send_text), INT(mode))
```